# this.results.rulesFired not getting defined

Tags: angular, typescript, ngoninit

I have the following table rows

```
<tr *ngFor="let firedRule of splitRules(results.rulesFired); let rowNumber = index"
            [class.added]="isAdd(firedRule)"
            [class.removed]="isRemove(firedRule)"
            [class.modified]="isModify(firedRule)">
```

Here is the splitRules function, which basically takes in a list of rules and break down each rule into new properties:

```
splitRules(firedRules: FiredRule[]) {
const regExRowNumber = /row\s*([0-9]+)/;
let rowMatch = [];
firedRules.forEach(rule => {
  let name = '';
  name = rule.ruleName.toLowerCase();
  rowMatch = regExRowNumber.exec(name);
  const rowNumber = rowMatch[1];
  const ruleName = name.substr(rowMatch[0].length).split('-')[0];
  const conditionsMatched = name.substr(rowMatch[0].length).split('-')[1];
  rule.groupName = ruleName.trim().replace('!', ': ').split(':')[0];
  rule.definitionName = ruleName.trim().replace('!', ': ').split(':')[1];
  rule.rowNumber = rowNumber;
  rule.conditionsMatched = conditionsMatched.trim();
  rowMatch = [];
});
return firedRules;
```

}

It's not a good practice to call the `splitRules` method inside the html, so I tried to call it on `ngOnInit` like this:

```
@Input() results: RulesEngineResponse;
ngOnInit(): void {
   this.results.rulesFired = this.splitRules(this.results.rulesFired);
}
```

And remove the call from html, however, I got `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'rulesFired' of null`, is there anyway to fix this?

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Please show more information. How is the `results` variable defined? What does `this.splitRules()` do and return?

Comment: Check if you're sending the correct values in the parent template: `<app-results [results]="results"...`. In the former example, please check if `results` is defined correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be because you are passing `Input() results` value as null from its parent component. Make sure you pass the `Input() results` value to that component.
If there is a scenario that you will pass that `Input() results` value later, then make a null check before you call `this.results`.

Answer (score 1):

Simple. `this.results` is undefined.

Edit: Since it's input, it's clear that the parent component pass a null reference to result. Try to initialize it on the parent.

Comment: It's not, it's an Input property.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have not defined the results variable as object and initiate in the `constructor` or `ngOnInit` whichever suits your use cases, as below

```
class component extends OnInit {
  public results: object<{rulesFired: Array<any>}>;

  constructor() {
   this.results: {rulesFired: []}
  }
   
}
```